# How to Send Data from Webserver to particular Android Device/Mobile Application

Tags: php, android

I am new to android and I am making an android app where whenever user logs in to an account using desktop browser (Chrome,Mozilla etc) a data has to be sent from Web server to particular android app if Android app/device is connected to internet or else just ignore/show some error message.

for example: There are two android apps one on x's android device and another same app on y's android device. Suppose user x logs into account using desktop browser (Chrome,Mozilla etc) a data needs to be sent to only x's android app from web server and not to y's android device.

How can we achieve this ?

Web Server Side (Backend) Preferably PHP. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try using Push notifications.
you can look at this. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is the easiest solution for your use case

on App Install ,get the user details  and generated token(one time) - save it in your backend.

on login from any other medium, get the token for that user and send push notification(it goes only to that device)

Comment: Thanks for your solutions. Firebase looks good idea,But I am planning to write my own code ,So any good suggestions for me to go ahead :) Thanks again